# A difference output with difference ways for make a list that only exist from the dictionary

Tags: python

first i used a list methods remove() to delete the item that doesn't exist in the dictionary values.
The code is like this:

```
rollNumber = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
sampleDict = {'Jhon':47, 'Emma':69, 'Kelly':76, 'Jason':97}
for num in rollNumber:
    if num not in sampleDict.values():
        rollNumber.remove(num)

print('After removing unwanted element from list', rollNumber)
```

output : [47,69,76,95,97]
this is wrong answer

the second one i made a empty list and used append() methods from the item that in dictionary.values
the code is like this:

```
rollNumber = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
sampleDict = {'Jhon':47, 'Emma':69, 'Kelly':76, 'Jason':97}
new = []
for num in rollNumber:
    if num in sampleDict.values():
        new.append(num)

print('After removing unwanted element from list', new)
```

output : [47,69,76,97]
this the correct answer

Do you guys know why this happens?

Comment: You're modifying the list while iterating over it. Create a copy of `rollNumber` using `rollNumber.copy()` or `list(rollNumber)`

Comment: when you remove items from iterated list then elements moves (they change position on list) and `for` may skip them - and this is why in Python we use second method.

Comment: Don't remove elements while iterating over it. Iterate over the copy and remove from original list. `for num in rollNumber[:]`

Comment: You can use set intersection: output = set(sampleDict.values()) & set(rollNumber)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you are deleting elements while iterating it. You're better off using a list comprehension:

```py
rollNumber = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
sampleDict = {'Jhon':47, 'Emma':69, 'Kelly':76, 'Jason':97}
rollNumber = [num for num in rollNumber if num in sampleDict.values()]

print('After removing unwanted element from list', rollNumber)
```

Outputs:

```py
After removing unwanted element from list [47, 69, 76, 97]
```

Comment: Don't you mean "using a list comprehension" rather than generator?

Comment: Nice its more effective

Comment: Hi @EvanAriawan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mutating the list, try using a comprehension to generate a new list

```
In [2]: vals = list(sampleDict.values())

In [3]: out = [v for v in rollNumber if v in vals]

In [4]: out
Out[4]: [47, 69, 76, 97]
```

Comment: Thanks for your sugesstion

Answer (score 0):

You try to modify a list while iterating on it, this is a common mistake.
Your 2nd way is the correct one, which can be written this way:

```
print([num for num in rollNumber if num in sampleDict.values()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are removing the element, it is not impacting the index of for loop and the for loop is skipping some list element due to the changed position of index once the number is removed.

```
        rollNumber = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
        sampleDict = {'Jhon': 47, 'Emma': 69, 'Kelly': 76, 'Jason': 97}

        for num in rollNumber:
            print(num)
            if num not in sampleDict.values():
                rollNumber.remove(num)
                print(rollNumber)

        print('After removing unwanted element from list', rollNumber)
```

Result

```
47
64
[47, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
37
[47, 69, 76, 83, 95, 97]
83
[47, 69, 76, 95, 97]
97
After removing unwanted element from list [47, 69, 76, 95, 97]
```

As you can see in the result for loop does not get executed for 69, 76 and 95 due to change in their index.

Comment: Ooo.. i see its because after we removed the item the index will change thanks man